# Get Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

How can I get the date in this format

> 1/11/2011 3:50:15 PM

using JavaScript.

Comment: Here's a [blog post](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) which might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look something like this. Because javascript does not have date formatting functions:

```
var d = new Date();
var date = [ d.getDate(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getFullYear() ];
var time = [
    (d.getHours() > 12) ? d.getHours() - 12 : (d.getHours() == 0) ? 12 : d.getHours(),
    d.getMinutes(),
    d.getSeconds()
];

"".concat(date.join("/"), " ", time.join(":"), " ", (d.getHours() > 11) ? "PM" : "AM");
```

*PS*: I hope that the AM/PM is good, I'm not really familiar with it.

*Edit*: I've checked it's okay now.

You can even use this to extend the `Date` class in the following way:

```
Date.prototype.getFormatted = function() {
    var date = [ this.getDate(), this.getMonth() + 1, this.getFullYear() ];
    var time = [
        (this.getHours() > 12) ? this.getHours() - 12 : (this.getHours() == 0) ? 12 : this.getHours(),
        this.getMinutes(),
        this.getSeconds()
    ];

    return "".concat(date.join("/"), " ", time.join(":"), " ", (this.getHours() > 11) ? "PM" : "AM");
};
```

and then simply:

```
var d = new Date();
d.getFormatted();
```

Comment: everything was helpful that you have posted accept the last line that is giving me error "".concat(date.join("/"), " ", time.join(":"), " ", (d.getHours() > 11) ? "PM" : "AM");
i tried to assign this  into something var test= d.concat(.......) it is not working

Comment: it's not `d.concat`, it's just `"".concat`, so `var test = "".concat(...`

Comment: i thought it is array concat but yup it is correct what you said.

Answer (score 0):

With the function getX you can get more information about the date, like month, day, year, fullyear.

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var day = currentTime.getDate();
```